# create table insert value postgresql - error 42601

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing for the first time here and i'm using Postgresql for the first time. I'm making this work for my thesis. Inserting the values into a column making a simple query the result is this:

```
INSERT INTO SCUOLA VIA TRENTO
VALUES
('VIA G. VERACROCE 49')
```

> ERRORE:  errore di sintassi a o presso "VIA"
>   LINE 1: INSERT INTO SCUOLA VIA TRENTO

********** Error **********

> ERRORE: errore di sintassi a o presso "VIA"
>   SQL state: 42601
>   Character: 20

I'm writing from Italy, so "via" means street and "errore di sintassi a o presso "VIA" means "syntax error near or in "VIA"".

Comment: To get English error messages run `SET LC_MESSAGES = C` in your session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between `INTO` and `VALUES` should be

```
table_name [ AS alias ] [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
```

So in your case, it should be a table name.

But `SCUOLA VIA TRENTO` is not a correct table name, because it contains spaces.
What is the exact name of the table?

If the table name *really* contains spaces, you'll have to enclose it in double quotes, like this:

```
INSERT INTO "SCUOLA VIA TRENTO" VALUES ...
```

**Note:** It is a good idea to use table names which contain only lower case characters, numbers and underscore (`_`) and begin with a letter.